# alsa mixer userspace application

Tags: alsa

I am going through amixer application. In this application there are two open functons:

1. snd_ctl_hw_open(&handle, NULL, card, 0)
2. snd_ctl_open(&handle, card, 0)

The first is interacting with the ALSA kernel, but I am not getting what the second function  is exactly doing.
**snd_ctl_hw_open(&handle, NULL, card, 0)** is there in **control_hw.c** which is called from amixer snd_card_get_index(optarg)

Comment: `control_hw.c` is not part of amixer; `snd_ctl_hw_open` is an implementation of the ALSA library. What is your actual problem?

Comment: If a give a command line argument for amixer as amixer -c 5 .... Now in the amixer application i am calling snd_card_get_index(optarg), i want to know what exactly this function is doing, and snd_ctl_open(&handle,card,0) internally calling snd_dlopen(), what exactly this means.

Comment: The internal implementation of ALSA device plugins is not documented, and I'm too lazy to write a book about it. `snd_dlopen` is used to load the library that implements the `hw` control plugin, which happens to be libasound itself. (Use [the Source](http://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-lib.git;a=tree), Luke!)

Comment: My actual Concern is in sound.c(sound/core) lnux has snd_open() function registered, from the user space through which function i am calling this function (snd_open()).

Comment: The kernel's `.open` function is invoked by `open("/dev/snd/controlC...")`.

Comment: My actual Concern is in sound.c(sound/core) linux has snd_open() function registered, from the user space through which function i am calling this function (snd_open()). Is my snd_ctl_open(&handle,card,0) function is calling snd_open(). In user-space, there are many library files such as control_hw.c control_shm.c control_ext.c all files have same function names (apart from functionality), when to use which file. Thanks for answering to me, please excuse me for my questions, as i am new to these topic, bit confused with some API'S

Comment: open("/dev/snd/controlC...") is there in which user space file

Comment: In `control_hw.c`. And why do you want me to explain the architecture of the entire ALSA library? What actual problem are you trying to solve?